# How can I show a field on click?

Tags: 8

In node.html.twig, I want to show a field when I click on it, as what the [Field Value Loader (Show field on click)](https://www.drupal.org/project/fvl) module does, but this module doesn't have releases for Drupal 8.

How can I do this?

Comment: after you click show, do you need to be able to hide?

Comment: For example my number is 1xxxxxx and I want that when I click on it show 1234567 .

Comment: yes, but after that do you want the ability to hide? or you don't need that?

Comment: No I don't need that .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**node.html.twig**

```
<div class = "field-something">
{{ content.field_something.value }}
</div>

<div class = "show">
Show
</div>
```

**custom.js**

```
(function ($) {

$('.field-something').hide();
$('.show').show();

$('.show').click(function(){
    $('.field-something').fadeIn(2000);
    $('.show').hide();
});

}(jQuery));
```

Your Theme's **style.css**

```
.field-something { float: left; padding-right: 5px; }
.show { color: blue; cursor: pointer; display: none; }
```

[Example DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/zo7zmgfr/25/)

Comment: In my source page number was show . How can I hide number in my page source until "show" not click ?

Comment: by default jQuery is disabled in D8, did you enable it?

Comment: In page my number is hide and when I click on "show" my number show . But when I watch my source page my nubmer is show . For more security I want hide on source page too .

Comment: Then you would have to load it using AJAX

Comment: How ? Can you help me ?

Comment: @SiMoNe just wondering, is that number a credit card number? or ???

Comment: That's users phone number . I want that robot spammers can't access that .

Comment: ah.. ok.. good idea, but that's a totally different question, I suggest you make a new one "How to load a user field value using AJAX"

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/202653/how-to-load-a-user-field-value-using-ajax

Answer (score 0):

```
var notificationList = false;
$('.show').click(function(){
    if(notificationList) {
       notificationList = false;
       $('.field-something').hide();
    } else {
       notificationList = true;
       $('.field-something').show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you explain a little your code?

Comment: Yes, By default, my window is not opened, so when I click on dropdown my variable notificationList is still false, accordingly the condition does not work and goes to else, after that my variable notificationList becomes true, and already the next click the condition is fulfilled and notificationList is set false , and the dropdown is hidden. Accordingly when I click my dropdown is hiding and showing.