# How to load a user field value using AJAX

Tags: 8, ajax

I want show my users phone number in node.html.twig and I want that robot spammers can't access that. In other words, the phone number should not show up in the page in the initial page load.

When a user clicks a <kbd>show</kbd> link/button the phone number should show up.

How can I do that?

Comment: Why do you want to do it in node.html.twig? In Drupal, AJAX is done in modules.

Comment: See here : http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/202649/how-can-i-show-a-field-on-click

Comment: That is JavaScript, not AJAX. Also that is a functionality of a module, not a theme. Would you change all the themes you use for a site, just to add that JavaScript?

Comment: Yes . Please help me that I do this .